# Cannot Invoke Filter With Argument List '((_) -> _)' [already implemented equatable]

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use filter on an array, but I keep getting this error. I checked the earlier answer, but I have already implemented "equatable" on my object.

Btw, what does this error mean anyway?

```
 // trying to use filter
var distance_array = [
    FilterOption(title: "0.5 miles", value:500, currentSetting: false)...]
var filtered_distance: [FilterOption]!
filtered_distance = distance_array.filter({ ($0.currentValue == true) })


// FilterOption Class
class FilterOption: NSObject, Equatable {

var title:String!
var value: AnyObject?
var currentSetting: Bool!

init(title:String, value:AnyObject?, currentSetting:Bool){
    self.title = title
    self.value = value
    self.currentSetting = currentSetting
}

class func convertDictionaryToFilterOption(dict:Dictionary<String, String>) -> FilterOption{
    return FilterOption(title:dict["name"]!, value:dict["code"]!, currentSetting: false)
}
```

}

```
func == (lhs: FilterOption, rhs: FilterOption) -> Bool {
  var title = (lhs.title == rhs.title)
  var setting = (lhs.currentSetting! == rhs.currentSetting!)

  return title && setting
}
```

Comment: where does the error happened?

Answer (score 1):

That compiler error is a little misleading. If you were really testing to see if one `FilterOption` was equal to another (a common problem that rears its head when comparing objects in `filter` closure), then you'd have to make it conform to `Equatable`. But that's not the problem here.

In this case the problem is simply that the code refers to `currentValue`, rather than `currentSetting`. If you fix that, the compiler error goes away.

---

By the way, you can simplify that `filter` statement:

```
let filteredDistance = distanceArray.filter { $0.currentSetting }
```

The `currentSetting` is already a `Bool`, so if you're testing to see if it's `true`, you can just return it directly. There were also some extraneous parentheses.